# math domain error python for quadratic equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm a complete beginner and for some reason when I try to run the code it says that there's a math domain error. I don't really understand what the problem is, help would be greatly appreciated:)

```
a = float(input('Rentrer la valeur de a : '))
b = float(input('Rentrer la valuer de b : '))
c = float(input('Rentrer la valuer de c : '))
delta = b**2 - 4*a*c

x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)
x2 = ((-b) - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)

console:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: What did you enter for `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: You're not dealing with the case where `delta` is negative (in which case the equation you're trying to solve would have no real solutions).

Comment: a= 5 b = 4 and c = -1

Comment: Can you find out and tell us what's the Python version you're running now?

Comment: how do i make it work for negative numbers then?

Comment: You could try to add this - `from math import sqrt`
(at the first line - very top by itself)

Comment: it's python3 i think

Comment: There is no solution for a negative delta (the function doesn't have roots, then). You need to handle this case explicitly.

Comment: If you run with this line I suggest you will get the results: 0.2 -1.0

Comment: i already have from math import *  in the beginning

Comment: yeah in my exercise it says that i should get 0.2 and -1.0

Comment: Interesting, I just run and get the results as yours.

Comment: 0.2 and -1.0 is what I get for a=5 b=4 c=-1
with your code

Comment: it worked with your code daniel, thank you!

Comment: Nothing change, Just add that `import' line. If that post did help, please select and accept it then. Thx

Comment: The code works perfectly and gives the expected output for your sample data - voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: ok, i thought ' math import * ' was enough but I got it now, thanks again

Comment: @Rii22 - glad that I can help. Please accept the post? as accepted.

Comment: how do i do that, nevermind found out

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is quite surprisingly easy: you need the `math` lib:

```
from math import sqrt

a = float(input('Rentrer la valeur de a : '))
b = float(input('Rentrer la valuer de b : '))
c = float(input('Rentrer la valuer de c : '))
delta = b**2 - 4*a*c

x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)
x2 = ((-b) - sqrt(delta)) / (2*a)

print(x1, x2)

"""
```

Answer (score 2):

The **sqrt** function must take as a parameter a **positive number**. When you enter the number *a*, *b*, and *c* you must make sure that the **delta** (discriminant) value is positive (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant https://www.expii.com/t/the-discriminant-of-a-quadratic-4540). If you enter the values a=1, b=3, c=-2 you won't see this error, since in this case the **delta** value is 17 (a positive number)

If you know what complex numbers are, you can use the sqrt function from the cmath package instead (from cmath import sqrt) and avoid this error, but you would be working with complex numbers.